# Adding SelectListItem() class without include System.Web.MVC in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on MVC.Net project which contains ViewModels and Controller. For why I don't use Model, because I use ADO.Net instead of Entity Framework for my DB connection.

To do so, I separate ViewModels with Controller in different project. Here is my problem,
I utilize SelectListItem class in `using System.Web.MVC`, but only install it in my Controller project.

Here example of Controller code snippet:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.ddlistname = new List<SelectListItem> {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Anthony", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Miranda", Value = "2" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Jhon", Value = "3" }
        };
        ViewBag.ddlistpos = new List<SelectListItem> {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Store Clerk", Value = "A" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Waiter", Value = "B" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Cook", Value = "C" }
        };
        var result = new CRViewModel();
        return View(result);
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmpName,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ddlistname )
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmpPost,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ddlistpos )
```

I know it's a bad practice to fill `List<SelectListItem>()` using ViewBag which resulted in a lot of ViewBag inside Controller, not to mention casting ViewBag in View.

Which why I want my ViewModels like this

```
public class CRViewModels
{
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public string EmpPos { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> EmpList = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Anthony", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Miranda", Value = "2" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Jhon", Value = "3" }
        };
    public List<SelectListItem> PosList = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Store Clerk", Value = "A" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Waiter", Value = "B" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Cook", Value = "C" }

        };
}
```

So in Controller I could write

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var result = new CRViewModel();
        return View(result);
    }
```

and in View :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmpName,Model.EmpList )
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmpPost,Model.PosList )
```

but I can't because in my ViewModels(VM) project, I don't have namespace `System.Web.MVC`. It's rather a waste if I add dll and include `System.Web.MVC` namespace to my VM project only for using the SelectListItem class.

If it is possible, How could I add SelectListItem class without adding whole namespace?

Edit :
for your request, I add my real code example
This is how my code works.

In DAL class:

```
public List<SelectListItem> getcustlist()
        {
            string SQL = "select cust_name, cust_id from tbl_cust";
            List <SelectListItem> result = getdropdownfromSQL(SQL, "cust_name", "cust_id ");
            return result;
        }
public List<SelectListItem> getpostype()
        {
            string SQL = "select pos_name, pos_code from tbl_pos";
            List<SelectListItem> result = getdropdownfromSQL(SQL, "pos_name", "pos_code");
            return result;
        }

public List<SelectListItem> getdropdownfromSQL(string SQL, string Text, string Value)
        {
            string Conn = GetConn();//function to get connection string
            List<SelectListItem> result = new List<SelectListItem>();
            string errmsg;
            DataTable fetch = getdt(SQL, Conn, out errmsg);
            if (fetch == null)
                return result;
            int rowaffect = fetch.Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < rowaffect; i++)
            {
                result.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = fetch.Rows[i][Text].ToString(),
                    Value = fetch.Rows[i][Value].ToString()
                });
            }
            return result;
        }

public DataTable getdt(string SQL, string strconn, out string errormsg)
        {
            errormsg = "";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strconn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, conn))
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errormsg = ex.Message;
                return null;
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

in controller :

```
private DAL func = new DAL();
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.ddlistname = func.getcustlist();
    ViewBag.ddlistpos = func.getpostype();
    var result = new CRViewModel();
    return View(result);
}
```

Comment: You need to add the namespace. And it makes sense to do so. Its a view model and is specific to a view in `System.Web.MVC`. And the namespace is being used in your app anyway, so it makes no difference (not clear why you think _its a waste_)

Comment: Because I use Nuget package from Visual Studio to add dll inside my project which need Internet Access. In my workplace, internet access is restricted. I can only access Intranet here. It's possible though to ask for temporary access, but somewhat complicated here, so a lot work to do.

Comment: Your using MVC so the `.dll` is already installed on your computer - you do not need to use Nuget

Comment: I use 5.0 MVC, machine only have up to 4.0

Comment: let suppose i use `System.Web.MVC` will it give any error?

Comment: and can you show how are you getting the data from database using ado

Comment: need to test if it works, can't do it right now because I don't have access to edit the source right now. Is it ok if I use different version of assembly in projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not achieve this behaviour without adding the namespace, as it stored info about this class.

However, you can create your own select item class and create an extension method for converting items of your class to `SelectListItem` as following:

```
public class SimpleItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

`SimpleItem` should be stored in assembly to which `ViewModel`s and `View`s have access.

And in the MVC project create an extension method:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions 
{
    public static MvcHtmlString LocalDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expr, 
        IEnumerable<SimpleItem> items)
    {
        return helper.DropDownListFor(expr, 
            items.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Text, Value = x.Value } ));
    }
}
```

You should include `System.Web.Mvc.Html` for enabling `DropDownListFor` method call from `helper`.

If it is your first `HtmlHelper` extension, would be better to include `namespace` of this class into page web.config. Or you will be required to include it on page manually:

```
@using YourProject.RequiredNamespace
```

After all you could simple call it on page:

```
@Html.LocalDropDownListFor(model => model.EmpName, Model.EmpList)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did tried to made my own selectlistitem method and not work. I did have helper extension my own. Will try it and mark as correct if It works. Wish me luck guys

Comment: Just a note. I did not accept this behaviour. IMO it is a kind of bad smell code to store dropdown values in the ViewModel, and there could be another solutions, as you can see from comments.

Comment: It's not a problem bc I stored it in dB and have functions to call it. Example is only for convinience