# Call SelectListItem in class library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a class library in solution. There are models and repositories and I want to create static list in class library to use in project. one of the static lists must return a list of data in "SelectListItem" type

```
   public class StaticLists
    {
        public List<SelectListItem> IsletmeTipleri()
        {
           return null
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting error;

> The type or namespace name 'SelectListItem' could not be found.

I should call 'using System.Web.Mvc' to use SelectListItem but I can't call in class library.

Can I call SelectListItem in class library?
How do I do if I can call ?

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640370/adding-selectlistitem-class-without-include-system-web-mvc-in-c-sharp

Comment: SelectList/SelectListItem are UI concerns.  Why not just return a Dictionary from your service layer and convert it to a SelectList in you UI project?

Comment: Have you added a reference to `System.Web.Mvc` in the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Reference of **System.Web.Mvc.dll** to you Class Libary project.

[image: Reference of System.Web.Mvc]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a recommended practice. Select List elements and the MVC is a presentation layer component. You must translate your select lists to a different object like a dictionary before sending to a class library and perform a reverse translation whenever you want to show that information in your presentation layer in form of a select list.